# How to read video frame buffer in windows

Tags: windows, video, buffer, frame

I am trying to create a small project wherein I need to capture/read the video frame buffer and calculate the average RGB value of the screen.
I don't need to write anything on the screen. I'm doing this in Windows.

Can anyone help me with any Windows API which will read the video frame buffer and calculate the average RGB value?

What I came to know is that I need to write a kernel driver which will have access to read the frame buffer.

1. Is this the only solution?
2. Is there any other way of reading frame buffer?
3. Is there an algorithm to calculate the RGB value from frame buffer data?

Comment: Do you need every frame?  Or can you just sample the screen (e.g. print screen) every couple of seconds?  The latter is easy.

Comment: Need to sample screen every second and then calculate the average RGB value of the buffer.

Comment: You won't have the CPU cycles to iterate over every pixel for every frame.  You'll need to sample one pixel from every NxN region on the screen.  Where N is say 10 or 20.

Comment: Yes, true. But how do I get the video frame buffer?

Comment: Search this site for "screen capture bitblt".  The BitBlt() technique is the most common way.  But if that doesn't meet perf goals search this site and the internet for "Screen Capture DirectShow"

Answer (score 1):

If you want really good performance, you might have to use directx and capture the backbuffer to a texture. Using mipmaps, it will automatically create downsamples all the way to 1X1. Justgrab the color of that 1 pixel and you're good to go.

Good luck, though. I'm working on implimenting this as we speak. I'm creating an ambient light control for my room. I was getting about 15FPS using device contexts and StretchBLT. Only got decent performance if I grabbed 1 pixel with GetPixel(). That's an i5 3570K @ 4.5GHz

But with the directx method, you could technically get hundreds if not thousands of frames per second. (when I make a spinning triangle, my 660 gets about 24,000 FPS. It couldn't be TOO much slower, minus the CPU calls.)